# How to convert TF_Tensor to opencv Mat in C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv

I am trying to port Python Tensorflow model to C++.
In process, I need to convert the TF_Tensor class to cv::Mat.

I created the output tensor as the below.

```
TF_Tensor** OutputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * NumOutputs);
```

Then I loaded model and the session was completed successfully, but I failed to convert OutputValues to cv::Mat.

I obtained a pointer to the data buffer by the code below.

```
const float* camBuf = (float*)TF_TensorData(*OutputValues);
```

But when I tried to create cv::Mat by the code below,

```
cv::Mat testInputImage(
        80,
        80,
        3,
        TF_TensorData(*OutputValues)
    );
```

Image is not generated correctly.

I could not find any reference to TF_Tensor data structure, so I am asking for a help.

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

```
cv::Mat testInputImage(80, 80, CV_32FC(3), TF_TensorData(*OutputValues));
```

you are "wrapping" the existing data in a `cv::Mat`, which avoids a copy. Note that the third argument should be `CV_32FC(3)` (a 32-bit floating point image, with 3 channels).
This approach should work if `OutputValues` is a `TF_Tensor**` type, and if the underlying `TF_Tensor` holds appropriate data.

However, I don't think that this:

```
TF_Tensor** OutputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * NumOutputs);
```

is an appropriate way to allocate a TF_Tensor; I think you should be using [TF_AllocateTensor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f0030f31d1e9021169d6f679c9021b21a79d90b0/tensorflow/c/tf_tensor.h#L93L104) instead.

All that said, if you are using C++, you might consider using [tf::Tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor) API instead of `TF_Tensor` (which is used for C, and is less common).

You omitted some details, but let's say your tensor is 4-dimensional (as is common), has float32 values, and is laid out as NxHxWxC (In other words, the tensor is holding a collection of float images).
If you want to convert `idx`-th element in the batch to a `cv::Mat`, you can do it like this:

```
tf::Tensor tensor = /* tensor from somewhere */;
int idx = /* index of the image in the batch */;

int batch_size = tensor.dim_size(0);
int rows = tensor.dim_size(1);                                                
int cols = tensor.dim_size(2);                                                
int channels = tensor.dim_size(3);                                            
int row_size = channels * cols * sizeof(float);                               
                                                                                
cv::Mat image(rows, cols, CV_32FC(channels));                                
auto tensor_mapped = tensor.tensor<float, 4>();                       
for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {                                              
  float* row = reinterpret_cast<float*>(mat.data + r * row_size);            
  for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {                                  
    for (int k = 0; k < channels; ++k) {                                      
      row[k + c * channels] = tensor_mapped(idx, r, c, k);                    
    }                                                                         
  }                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try :

cv::Mat mat(width, height, CV_32F);
std::memcpy((void *)mat.data, camBuf , sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * NumOutputs);
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I already tried this method. I guess the problem is the image data type issue. But thank you anyways.